# Symfony Forms-Displaying the form details in a label

Tags: html, symfony

Guys Im very new to Sympfony Forms. I created a form and now i want to display those data from the form on a separate page. the data must be only text and not editable. can u guys help me out here? i want to get the output of the 'firstname' from the form and display it as just a text.Thank You.

```
{% extends 'FirstPrj/mainbase.html.twig' %}
```

{% block body %}

```
    <!-- row start -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>First Name</h3>
                {{ form_widget(form.firstName) }}
                {#<label for="first-name">First Name*</label>#}
            </div>
```

Comment: If you just want text then simply pass the entity to the template you don't need a form. Or you can create read only form. For that in your Type class add "read_only" => true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sergei Kutanov pointed already out, if you only want to show the data, there is no need for a form. However, it would be possible to access the data via form like this in your twig template:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <h3>First Name</h3>
    {{ form.firstName.vars.value }}
  </div>
```

You could also dump e.g. the `firstName` field of your `form`, just to get a closer look what is going on there and which `vars` you can access.

```
{{ dump(form.firstName) }}
```